# Web caching algorithm (hashmaps keys-values issue?)

Tags: java, caching, hashmap, key, key-value

I am newbee in programming in general and in Java in particular. The last few months I am working on a project regarding a Web caching algorithm. After a lot of work I have done everything (and since this is my first real project, I am very happy about that) except one little but important detail. Let me be more precise on that.

In the code I generate random Zipf-distributed requests. Each requested item is distinguished by its numeric ID (reqID). The cache is implemented as a doubly linked list (a Java LinkedList). The caching algorithm is called WeightLFU and it works as follows:

Each request is assigned a weight which is given by the formula

```
    weight = Math.pow(1/p, reqIndex);
```

where p is a weight factor and reqIndex is the numeric index of the request (1st, 2nd, 3rd etc.).

The score (which I call weighted frequency, weightFreq) of each cached item is given as the sum of its weights. Let us see an example to illustrate this. Assume that we have the following request stream (the reqIDs are given):

ReqIndex: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
ReqID:    7 | 3 | 7 | 1 | 3

Assuming p= 0.5 (just a convenient value), the weights assigned to each request are:

ReqIndex: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
Weight:   1 | 2 | 4 | 8 | 16

Therefore, the score of the requested item with reqID 7 is 1 + 4 = 5, the score of the item with reqID 3 is 2 + 16 = 18 and finally the score of the item with reqID 1 is 8.

Now here is what I do wrong. In this example, I would have the following: the score of item 3 would be 16+8+4+2+1 = 31, the score of item 1 would be 8+4+2+1 = 15 etc., i.e. the code sums all the previous weights irrespective of the request ID. Here are the relevant parts of the code:

Class WeightLFU

```
    public class WeightLFU {

//////////////////////////////////////////
// member attributes

/** weightLFU cache */
private List<Request> weightLFU = new LinkedList<Request>();

/** Max cache size */
private int M;

/** Fading factor */
private double p;

/** Weight */
private double weight;

/** Score (weightFreq) */
private double weightFreq;

/** Map of reqID (K) and weight (V) */
private Map<Integer, Double> weights;

/** Map of reqID (K) and weightFreq (V) */
private Map<Integer, Double> weightFreqs;

    //////////////////////////////////////////
// member methods

    // constructor, printing methods, initializers etc.

    /**
 * Getter for weight of request
 * @param   request                                 The requested item
 * @param   reqIndex                                The index of the request
 * @return  this.weights.get(request.reqID)     The weight of the request
 */
public double getWeight(Request request, int reqIndex) {

    // calculate weight
    weight = Math.pow(1/p, reqIndex);

    // put request along with its weight to the weights map
    weights.put(request.reqID, weight);

    // return weight of requested item
    return this.weights.get(request.reqID);

}

/**
 * Calculate weightFreq of requested item
 * @param   request    The requested item
 * @param   reqIndex   Index of the request     
 */
public void calcWeightFreq(Request request, int reqIndex) {

    // initialize weightFreq
    initWeightFreqs(request);

    // calculate weight freq
    weightFreq += getWeight(request, reqIndex);

    // put reqID along with its weightFreq into the weightFreqs map
    weightFreqs.put(request.reqID, weightFreq);

}

/**
 * Getter for weightFreq of requested item
 * @param   request                                 The requested item
 * @return  this.weightFreqs.get(request.reqID);    weightFreq of req. item
 */
public double getWeightFreq(Request request) {

    // return weightFreq of requested item
    return this.weightFreqs.get(request.reqID);

}

    // other stuff (cache lookup, insertion, replacement etc.)
}
```

The reason I use a method calcWeightFreq and another method as getter instead of combining them in a single getter method is just to avoid using as parameter the reqIndex when I call the getter method in cache insertion and replacement operations latter on. It is irrelevant of my issue.

Main class:

```
    // several irrelevant stuff

    // scan the request list
    for(int ir = 0; ir < reqs.size(); ir++) {

        // assign the item in position ir in the reqs list to a Request item r
    Request r = reqs.get(ir);

       // other stuff

}

// other stuff

}
```

I understand that this abnormal behavior makes sense. I assume that in the calcWeightFreq method I have to scan the weights map in order to get the sum of the weights only for the specific reqID, but this does not work either (I get 0 value for all the weightFreq values).

I hope I have clearly stated the issue. I assume that it needs only 5-10 lines of additional code to be addressed, but I don't know how to do it. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I did that because I thought I have to associate its weight with a request ID in order latter on, in the calcWeightFreq, to get the sum of weights for each individual reqID and thus calculate its score, instead of summing all the previous weights as I do now.

Comment: You haven't shown enough code.

Comment: @RobinGreen    I had the exact opposite feeling, I thought that I have posted too much code! The problem IMO is located at the method where I calculate the score (WeightFreq). I should somehow take advantage of the fact that I have associate a reqID to each weight using a relevant HashMap weights in order to take the sum of the weights of each individual reqID in that method. But I don't know how. It should be something like for(Entry<Integer, Double> entry : this.weights.entrySet) { // stuff } or something like that. But I am still a newbee I think!